# Nested Loop (XSL) only indent top iterations

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to format XML to text like this

```
ab
ab
```

This is 
This is the XML

```
<Doc>
<line>
    <letter>
        <value>a</value>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <value>b</value>
    </letter>
</line>
<line>
    <letter>
        <value>a</value>
    </letter>
    <letter>
        <value>b</value>
    </letter>
</line>
</Doc>
```

This is the XSL:

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Doc/line">
    <xsl:for-each select="letter">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Should I add in a line break manually

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

or is there a way to use the xsl:output to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the line break with e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Doc/line">
    <xsl:for-each select="letter">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```